# Click event not working in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have something basically like that. I'm adding buttons in a loop, but when I click in them it doesn't work.

```js
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#add").append(
         '<button class ="addx"> Add </button>'
        )
    }

    $(".addx").click(function(){
     alert("ADDED");
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add"></div>
```

Comment: Fix your unclosed `click()` binding and your logic works fine.

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a `);` at the end of your script to close the `click` method.

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $("#add").append(
     '<button class ="addx"> Add </button>'
    )
}

$(".addx").click(function(){
    alert("ADDED");
}); // here
```

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically created elements you will want to restructure the event listener:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addx', function(){
        alert("ADDED");
    });
```

The massive stream of comments ultimately concluded that older versions of IE indeed support `.click` and the approved answer is correct.

The listener listed here is for asynchronous javascript where the appended elements are added after the event listener was declared, like in a callback method or something.

Special thanks to Taplar who endured my insanity while we went through the fun of setting this up in test environments. It was a hoot, but in the end Taplar was absolutely correct as well as everyone else who called out this as an option, but not the definitive answer to this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

```js
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $("#add").append(
         '<button class ="addx"> Add </button>'
        )
    }

    $(".addx").click(function(){
     alert("ADDED");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add"></div>
```